# very basic python GUI program help

Tags: python, user-interface

So I'm working on a pretty basic program in which one of three "doors" is randomly selected.  This choice is compared with the user's choice and the user wins if his choice is the same as the randomly selected one.

So basically, I want to re-set the text in the GUI based on whether the user is correct or not.  There is a "setText" method in the graphics library that I'm using (comes with the textbook) that should do the trick but for some reason I keep getting this error:

```
label.setText("Congrats! You got it!")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'setText'
```

But I'm certain that setText is a method for the text class!

```
user_select = win.getMouse()

for i in range(n):

    selection = door_list[randrange(0,3)]
    user_select = win.getMouse()
    label = Text(Point(5,9), "hello").draw(win)

    if selection.clicked(user_select):
        label.setText("Congrats! You got it!")
        wins = wins + 1

    elif not selection.clicked(user_select):
        label.setText("Sorry, try again")
        losses = losses + 1

print(wins, losses)
```

Comment: Which toolkit are you using? I believe that attribute error means that label == None, as in it's never getting set.

Comment: First line of defense is to take the error message literally. Notice it says "'NoneType' object has no attribute..." rather than "'Label' object has no attribute...". In other words, it's not that the object is missing the attribute, it's that the object is None.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't whether this is a complete fix, but you need to replace this:

```
label = Text(Point(5,9), "hello").draw(win)
```

with this:

```
label = Text(Point(5,9), "hello")
label.draw(win)
```

In your version, the `Text` object is created and drawn, but it's the return value of the `draw` function that gets assigned to `label` (and presumably, `draw` returns `None`).

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing your textbook or the API, I would guess that the `draw` method of `Text` does not return the `Text`, so you'll need to break this out into two lines:

```
label = Text(Point(5,9), "hello")
label.draw(win)
```